# Authentication issue using Rally WebServices

Tags: rally

I am trying to call some Rally WebServices from an App inside Rally to update Portfolio Item details (SubFeatures) and I hit a problem that a search on Stack OVerflow indicated I needed to use:

https://rally1.rallydev.com:443/slm/webservice/v2.0/security/authorize

When I GET this it requires me to log in with my Rally userID/Password.

How should I use this properley from within a Rally App so as to not need this authentication since i am already logged in.

As a secondary factor, ulrimately I am to call 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/portfolioitem/' + id

and I assume I would need to pass something like:  { "PortfolioItem": { "Description": "hello" } }

Am I barking up wrong trees there?

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you manually wrangling the ajax calls yourself?  App SDK 2.0 does a lot of this for you (including the security token piece mentioned above).  Check out this example, which demonstrates performing a full CRUD lifecycle within an app:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/data_models